# Having trouble getting fields to update in real time depending on inputs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So what I'm aiming to do is have a field update based on the inputs of two other fields. Currently, the fields are all manual input, but below is the code I've been trying to use to get the "passThru" field to update in real time as I enter data into the other fields.

Almost all of the code we're working with is either React.JS or javascript, with some bootstrap styling.

I'm going to continue trying to solve this with a few other methods, but any help I can get is greatly appreciated.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangePassOn = this.onChangePassOn.bind(this);
        this.onChangePassOff = this.onChangePassOff.bind(this);
        this.onChangePassThru = this.onChangePassThru.bind(this);
        this.handlePassengerCalculation = this.handlePassengerCalculation.bind(this);
}


onChangePassOn(e) {
        const passOn = { val: e.target.value, index: this.props.legindex }

        this.setState(...this.state, {passOn: e.target.value});
                
        this.props.handleChangePassOn(passOn);
    }

    onChangePassOff(e) {
        const passOff = { val: e.target.value, index: this.props.legindex }

        this.setState(...this.state, {passOff: e.target.value});
                
        this.props.handleChangePassOff(passOff);
    }

    onChangePassThru(e) {
        const passThru = { val: e.target.value, index: this.props.legindex }
        
        this.props.handleChangePassThru(passThru);
    }

    // handling the calculation of Passengers on/off/thru

    handlePassengerCalculation(event){
        let passOn = this.state.passOn;
        let passOff = this.state.passOff;
        let passThru = passOn - passOff;
        console.log(passThru);        
    }

 <div className="col">
    <div className="row">
       <label>Passengers</label>
          </div>
             <div className="row">
               <input type="text" className="form-control" id="passon" data-test="passon" onChange={this.onChangePassOn} name="passon" placeholder="Passengers On"></input>
               <input type="text" className="form-control" id="passoff" data-test="passoff" onChange={this.onChangePassOff} name="passoff" placeholder="Passengers Off"></input>
               <input type="text" className="form-control" id="passthru" data-test="passthru" onChange={this.onChangePassThru} name="passthru" value={passThru}></input>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it is now solved. The code is below(obviously with the methods bound, but everything not written below is the same).

````
    onChangePassOn(e) {
        const passOn = { val: e.target.value, index: this.props.legindex }
        
        this.setState({passengerOn: e.target.value}, this.handlePassengerCalculation);
 
        this.props.handleChangePassOn(passOn);
        
    }

    onChangePassOff(e) {
        const passOff = { val: e.target.value, index: this.props.legindex }
        
        this.setState({passengerOff: e.target.value}, this.handlePassengerCalculation);
        
        this.props.handleChangePassOff(passOff);
        
    }

    // handling the calculation of Passengers on/off/thru

    handlePassengerCalculation(){
        const totalPassenger = (this.state.passengerOn - this.state.passengerOff);
        this.setState({passengerThru: totalPassenger}); 
        // console.log(passThru);  
        const passThru = { val: (this.state.passengerOn - this.state.passengerOff), index: this.props.legindex };
         this.props.handleChangePassThru(passThru);      
    }
    ```
````